# Laravel 6.11: Shopping cart HasMany::fisrt() in Accessor not working

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-6, accessor

EDIT: typos corrected (made while translating some of the code)

I'm building a shopping cart with Laravel 6.11 (MAMP).
I am getting a couple of errors that are driving me nuts. Please help! 
First I'll give you the code, afterwards the errors:

Table carts:

```
id
order_date
arrived_date
status
user_id
```

Table cart_details:

```
id
cart_id
product_id
quantity
discount
```

Please note that the two tables are EMPTY at this point, no records inserted just yet.

A cart can have many cartdetails. So in Cart.php I have:

```
class Cart extends Model
{
    public function details()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(CartDetail::class);
    }
}
```

CartDetailController contains:

```
class CartDetailController extends Controller
{
    //let's insert data in  cart_details so the order can be created
    public function store(Request $request)
    {

        $cartDetail = new CartDetail();

        $cartDetail->cart_id = auth()->user()->cart_identification;/* cart_id from the logged user. In User.php I have getCartIdentifitacionAttribute, I'm going to put the code right after this */

        $cartDetail->product_id = $request->product_id;
        $cartDetail->quantity = $request->quantity;

        $cartDetail->save();

        return back();
    }
}
```

In User.php I have:

```
  public function carts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Cart::class); //a user can have many carts
    }
    public function getCartIdentificationAttribute()
    {
        $cart = $this->carts()->where('status','Active')-> first();

        if($cart)
        {
            return $cart->id;
        }
        else// if there's no cart, let's create a new one
        {
            $cart = new Cart();
            $cart->status = 'Active';
            $cart->user_id = $this->id;
            $cart->save();
            return $cart->id;

       }
    }
```

The .blade (which will show the administrator the details of the order):

```
@foreach (auth()->user()->cart_identification->details as $detail)

      <ul>
            <li>{{ $detail }}</li>
        </ul>
@endforeach
```

And now the errors, two... certainly related :(

1. In a product page, after hitting "Add to the Cart":

   BadMethodCallException
   Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany::fisrt()

If I print `$this->carts()->where('status','Active')` it works, it is when I add `->fist()` that the error shows

2. When accesing the blade as an administrator would do to deal with the order:

   Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException
   Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany::fisrt() (View: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/app-shop/resources/views/home.blade.php)

If I print `auth()->user()` it works, it is `auth()->user()->cart_identification` that causes the error.

What am I missing??

Thanks a ton!!

Comment: I hope it’s a mistype, but method name is first()

Comment: There are several mistypes: 1. getCartIdentificationAttribute and later you use cart_identificacion instead of cart_identification; 2. first() is misspelled as fist() and fisrt()

Comment: @DanielProtopopov I doubt it's a mistype in the question itself; `fisrt` shows up in several spots that look like direct quotes. Looks like OP definitely has a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a `typo error`.

It should be

```
$cart = $this->carts()->where('status','Active')->first();
```

Not

```
 $cart = $this->carts()->where('status','Active')->fisrt();
```

And in your model change your code to this.

```
public function scopeCartIdentification()
    {
        $cart = $this->carts()->where('status','Active')->first();

        if($cart)
        {
            return $cart->id;
        }
        else// if there's no cart, let's create a new one
        {
            $cart = new Cart();
            $cart->status = 'Active';
            $cart->user_id = $this->id;
            $cart->save();
            return $cart->id;

       }
}
```

and call in to your controller like this

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {

        $cartDetail = new CartDetail();

        $cartDetail->cart_id = auth()->user()->CartIdentification();/* cart_id from the logged user. In User.php I have getCartIdentifitacionAttribute, I'm going to put the code right after this */

        $cartDetail->product_id = $request->product_id;
        $cartDetail->quantity = $request->quantity;

        $cartDetail->save();

        return back();
    }
```

Comment: yo don't need to call the word scope in the function cause laravel also knows that

Answer (score 0):

Where does Auth()->user()->**cart_identificacion** come from?
You can use relationships like that:

```
Auth::user()->carts->id
```

or you use your function like that:

```
Auth::user()->getCartIdentificationAttribute()
```